# Resizing an image before displaying it in the browser

Tags: php, image, laravel, resize

I'm creating an API in which I have a model called `OnlineAds()`, it has these columns `title`, `full_discription`, `short_discription` and `image`, I also created an input form to fill in these fields and upload an image, in the `image` field I add the image's name and store the image in this path: `storage/uploads`. I was able to retrieve the image and display it, but I still didn't figure out how to resize it before displaying (lets say I want it to be 300 x 300), can anybody show me how ?

Note: I tried to use Stapler and Imagine but they seemed to give multiple bugs and failed!

This is my controller:

```
public function show()
{
 $img = OnlineAds::find(50)->image;

    $path = storage_path('uploads') . '/' . $img;

    if (File::exists($path)) {

        $filetype = File::type($path);

        $response = Response::make(File::get($path), 200);

        $response->header('Content-Type', $filetype);
        return $response;

    }

}
```

Comment: What were the _multiple bugs_ with **Stapler** and **Imagine**? Maybe we can help fix them.

Comment: @Peh some classes couldn't be reached when i called them, I fixed this, but still struggling with this line

     $response = Response::make(
            Image::resize($filename, $size),
           200
        );
it says that i cannot call the Image class statically while it is unstatically defined

Comment: try with a new instance of image: `$image = new Image` and then call its resize function `$response = Response::make($image->resize($filename, $size), 200 );`

Comment: @Peh I tried that before and got this error 

Undefined property: App\Libraries\Image\Image::$library

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could look into using [Intervention](http://image.intervention.io/) to take care of the image processing as well as handling the response. It can be as easy as this:

```
public function show()
{
    $img = OnlineAds::find(50)->image;
    $path = storage_path('uploads') . '/' . $img;

    if (File::exists($path)) {
        $img = Image::make($path);
        $img->resize(300, 300);

        return $img->response();
    }
}
```

There are [detailed instructions](http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/installation) on how to install the Intervention library and integrate it with Laravel, and it shouldn't take more than a few minutes to get it up and running.

Comment: You just need to run this composer command in your Laravel application directory `php composer.phar require intervention/image`, then add two things in your `config/app.php`: this `'Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider'` to the `$providers` array and this `'Image' => 'Intervention\Image\Facades\Image'` to the `$aliases` array. How is that not simple?? There are three steps to do and it's installed.

Comment: that's what i was trying to do, the php composer doesn't work , it give me back this line 

Could not open input file: composer.phar

Comment: How did you install laravel without composer then?

Comment: @SaifHarbia If you haven't installed composer you can read up on how to do that [here](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md). Then your composer command will work.

Comment: @lamzozo You could get Laravel from [LaraPack](http://fian.my.id/larapack/), but in this case I think it's an older project that had the dependencies already installed (especially because it's Laravel 4).

Comment: @Bodgan  I know how to install composer, I have it working correctly, so composer is not the problem im facing, I meant that the composer command given to install intervention doesn't work and it gives back the error line i wrote above

Comment: @SaifHarbia What OS are you running? And when you run other composer commands for your Laravel project how are you running them? (there may be some alias problems with composer, if it works for you in other cases and not when trying to install Intervention).

Comment: @Bogdan I'm working on windows 7, I tried to install stapler and imagine packages with composer and it worked, i simply run the command php composer auto-load after inserting the special line for both libraries into composer and config/app.php files,, nevertheless, i couldn't have them running correctly for that some errors were returned as some dependencies were incorrectly written and i didnt know how to fix them

Comment: Then try running `php composer require intervention/image` instead (without the `.phar`).

Comment: Success!! the only thing i needed to do is to write the command as such: composer require intervention/image. 
As Im working in windows 7 environment